# Итерация каждых 5 раз

Tags: python, for

есть одна проблема, вот у меня есть цикл `for i in range(100):` как мне сделать проверку на итерацию каждых 5 раз, тоесть i прибавилось к текущему +5 и выполняется тело цикла, и так до 100 раз?

Comment: Просто сделать range с шагом 5? `range(0, 100, 5)`

Comment: Если часть действий надо делать каждый раз, а часть только каждый пятый:
```if i % 5 == 0:```

Comment: Просто делать не до 100, а до 20

Answer (score 0):

я не особо понял ваше условие проверки, но как то так:

```py
for i in range(100):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        do_something():
        continue
```

тут я проверяю, что итерация каждая пятая

Comment: хотя и `continue` тут не нужен, если только вы не хотите чтобы часть кода выполнялась только при каком то условии